# Carregar e ler XML via AJAX Cross-Domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

Tenho uma requisição AJAX Cross-Domain que recebe um XML. Depois de muito trabalho, consegui baixar o XML mas não sei se fiz isto da forma correta pois ele nunca chega no *success*. Segue o código da requisição:

```
function refreshPage() {

$.ajax({ url: 'http://finansite-a.ae.com.br/localiza/xml/localiza.xml',
    crossDomain: true, 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (response) {
        $(response).find('li a').each(function () {
            listHref.push($(this).attr('href'));
        });

        var nome_arquivos = new Array();
        var DHTML = (document.getElementById || document.all || document.layers);
        var xmlDocWin;
        var ini_coluna_win;
        function pegarDiv(nome) {
            if (document.getElementById) {
                this.obj = document.getElementById(nome);
            }
            else if (document.all) {
                this.obj = document.all[nome];
            }
            else if (document.layers) {
                this.obj = document.layers[nome];
            }
        }

        function escrever_campo(id, texto) {
            if (!DHTML) return;
            var x = new pegarDiv(id);
            if (x.obj) {
                x.obj.innerHTML = texto;
            }
            return;
        }

        function pegaCor(valor) {
            cor = 'semvar';
            temp = valor.replace(",", ".");
            if (parseFloat(temp) == 0)
                cor = 'semvar';
            else if (parseFloat(temp) > 0)
                cor = 'varpos';
            else if (parseFloat(temp) < 0)
                cor = 'varneg';
            return cor;
        }

    }

});}
```

Ao baixar o XML, é mostrado no console do Google Chrome a seguinte mensagem de erro falando do XML: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <* na linha 1 (cabeçalho).

Comment: Veja a Network do seu navegador, e vê o status dessa requisição se é 200, 304, 403, 404 ou 500

Comment: @TafarelChicotti mas eu não quero tratar o erro, eu quero que não precise dar erro.

Comment: @TafarelChicotti status 200. Editei a pergunta e coloquei uma mensagem de erro que o Google Chrome exibe referindo-se ao XML.

Comment: Fala que linha está acontecendo o erro tbm?

Comment: @TafarelChicotti linha 1. Logo no cabeçalho.

Comment: onde vc colocou `jsonp`, muda para `xml`

Comment: @TafarelChicotti aí o cross-domain não funciona. Dá erro de permissão: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://finansite-a.ae.com.br/localiza/xml/localiza.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3064' is therefore not allowed access".

Comment: poem como `html` o retorno e usa o `var $xml = $(data).parseXML();` e tenta ver o se vai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que você determinou o tipo de dados como JSONP, isso significa que o resultado do *request* que você está fazendo retornará um JSON que será executado num *callback* definido por você, ou seja, supondo que a url que você está chamando retorne o seguinte JSON: `{"Name": "Foo", "Id" : 1234, "Rank": 7}`, no caso do JSONP você deveria acrescentar ao final da URL que você está fazendo a requisição `?jsonp=callback`, e então a requisição pegaria o JSON de resultado e passaria como parâmetro para a função *callback* como por exemplo: `callback({"Name": "Foo", "Id" : 1234, "Rank": 7});`

O primeiro e principal problema é que a sua requisição não está retornando um JSON e sim um XML, e o segundo problema, é que você não está passando nenhuma função de *callback*, dessa forma, quando o jQuery tenta parsear a resposta para passar de parâmetro para a sua função de *callback* ele não consegue, pois ele tenta parsear um JSON mas na verdade é um XML.

Eu recomendaria que você fizesse isso com uma linguagem de *backend* ao invés de tentar utilizar JS.

Você tem várias opções de *backend* para fazer esse tipo de processamento:
em PHP você tem a lib [CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php)
em Python você tem a [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)
em Ruby você tem a classe [Net::HTTPRequest](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPRequest.html)

Assim como em outras linguagens você tem suas respectivas bibliotecas que fazem HTTP Requests além das bibliotecas para tratar XML, o que vai facilitar pra você, parsear a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui resolver dessa forma!